X Twitter Sign In C# Web API
I'm trying to figure out how the Twitter API works. I successfully post a tweet. Thanks to this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U69cDi9KLRU
But now my problem, how to apply the Twitter Sign-In where users will login/authenticate so I can post tweets on their page. What I need to do is I can post on their behalf that's why I need to authenticate them. Maybe somebody have done this or someone could guide me on this? I'm using TweetInviAPI library.
As of now, only posting tweets is the only thing I can make work because of the tutorial.
